# react.js, npm serve and "async isDebugging" error

Tags: reactjs

When I run my app from the started from : `create-react-app`
I have builded and run

```
serve -s build
```

then I have this error:

```
const updateCheck = async isDebugging => {
                      ^^^^^^^^^^^
SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
at Object.exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:78:16)
at Module._compile (module.js:543:28)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:580:10)
at Module.load (module.js:488:32)
at tryModuleLoad (module.js:447:12)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:439:3)
at Module.runMain (module.js:605:10)
at run (bootstrap_node.js:420:7)
at startup (bootstrap_node.js:139:9)
at bootstrap_node.js:535:3
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`async` is fairly new so my first guess would be to [update](https://www.hostingadvice.com/how-to/update-node-js-latest-version/) your version of `node`

Comment: facepalm - when I was working same things 2 months ago it worked on the version of node I had. After update it worked of course :)